# Front-end get wrong data from back-end

Tags: javascript, go

For example:

Go back-end sends:

```
map{"1": 0, "2": 1}
```

JavaScript front-end uses [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) to get data from back-end:

```
{"2": 1, "1": 0, "3": 1}
```

Is it possible that front-end got data which has one (or two) more element  accidentally?

Comment: There's no way for us to debug your program if you don't share your code with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible, there must be something wrong in your code. 
two options in my opinion.

1. make sure your Go Back-end sends right data.
2. capture data using software `wireshark`.